# javascript not loading in HTML file - nodejs + expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am new to nodejs and expressjs so Im trying to build simple web app to grasp both frameworks.
Here I have built a project with the following architecture:

```
js
   test.js
views
   index.html
server.js
```

my server file looks like this:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = 1337;
var express = require("express");
var ejs =  require("ejs");

var server = express();
server.use(server.router);
server.use(express(__dirname)); 
server.set('view engine','html');
server.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

server.get("*", function(request, response){ 
    response.render('index.html');
});

server.listen(port, host);
```

and my index file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript"  src="/js/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="starter-template">
           some code
        </div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->
</body>
</html>
```

My index.html file loads properly but I cannot get the test.js file to load. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: in the terminal I dont get any error but on the client side I get this:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < bootstrap.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < test.js:1

Comment: @ArnaudDrizard if console reports you an error in test.js it mean that test.js have been loaded at least :)

Comment: Is your `test.js` file validated? and where is `bootstrap.min.js` coming from?

Comment: what I dont get is that I only put  console.log('test'); in test.js and nothing gets printed

Comment: oops sorry the error in the console was the old one - I removed the bootstrap.min.js from my project so now the error is only:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < test.js:1

Comment: @ArnaudDrizard Probably you should to show your test.js listing.

Comment: @Spearfisher, I have the same problem. What is your solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use *express.static* built-in middleware function in Express.

Add this line after server.engine. This mechanism should allow static files to be served e.g. images, javascripts, css

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
```

Now you can load:

```
http://localhost:1337/js/test.js
```

Answer (score 0):

change render into sendfile and move your js folder to public folder then add this middleware 
server.use(express(__dirname+'/public'));

Answer (score 0):

JS files are rendered as static files.
Ref: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
First create a folder "static" and keep .js files in it.
Now, correct the script tags of these .js files in .ejs file.

Answer (score 0):

in the nodejs side :

```
var path    = require("path");
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/js')));//middleware
```

in the HTML page :

```
<script src="./my_script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As this files is static, you should add the entire root directory to 'app'.

Like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
```

So that you can quote all of your files by relative path.